# Python pandas - How do I merge two data frames based on dates that are not consistent in both?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I currently have two very large data sets:

***df1***:

```
                    created_at  PM1.0_CF1_ug/m3  ...  PM2.5_ATM_ug/m3  Unnamed: 9
0    2019-08-08 18:00:00+00:00             4.46  ...             8.78         NaN
1    2019-08-08 19:00:00+00:00             0.00  ...             0.00         NaN
```

***df2***:

```
                    created_at  REF
0    2019-08-08 17:00:00+00:00             1.08
1    2019-08-08 18:00:00+00:00            84.31
```

Not all of the `created_at` values given in ***df1*** apprear in ***df2***, which is a smaller data frame than the first.

What I would like to do is merge/join the two tables based on the `created_at` values given in ***df2*** and have a `REF` column in the merged table which only shows up on the dates that were originally in ***df2***.

Here is an example of what I would like:

```
                    created_at  PM1.0_CF1_ug/m3  ...  PM2.5_ATM_ug/m3  Unnamed: 9         REF
0    2019-08-08 18:00:00+00:00             4.46  ...             8.78         NaN       84.31
1    2019-08-08 19:00:00+00:00             0.00  ...             0.00         NaN         NaN
```

Maybe it's possible to do this in SQL and then convert it to a pandas DF, however I'm familiar with SQL joins.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using [pandas merge?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='created_at', how='left', indicator=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `pd.merge_asof`  and specify a tolerance.  Or, merge on just the dates instead of the datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would typically use a `left join` to optionnaly bring the matching row from `df2`:

```
select df1.*, df2.ref
from df1
left join df2 on df2.created_at = df1.created_at
```

When there is no match in `df2`, column `ref` will come up as `null` in the resultset.